# Slidden, Chidden, Blent, Hove, Rove, Shodden, Gilt, Girt

Tags: irregular-forms

Now, I'm doing complete research on semi-irregular verbs, so I really need your help in order to know how often you use each verb (the **irregular** form of it), whether it's grammatically correct nowadays, and whether it'd generally be understood if I used it instead of the contemporary regular form.

The dubious ones are (bolded):

1. Shoe: shod-shod/**shodden**.
2. Chide: chided/chid-chided/chid/**chidden**.
3. Slide: slid-slid/**slidden**.
4. Heave: heaved/**hove**-heaved/**hove**.
5. Reeve: reeved/**rove**-reeved/**rove**.
6. Blend: blended/**blent**-blended/**blent**.
7. Gild: gilded/**gilt**-gilded/**gilt**.
8. Gird: girded/**girt**-girded/**girt**.

Please, don't accuse me of trying to find such archaic things out; I'm just a curious guy, wanting to know more about the English language.

Also, would you mind telling me what the **verb** *to reeve* means: I cannot find it out, yet dictionaries do recognise it as one.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Every word is different. And every *context* is different, even if we focus on just one verb here. I doubt I've ever seen ***shodden, chidden, slidden*** before, but I'd probably understand them in context. ***Hove, gilt,*** and ***girt*** are just ordinary words to me, but ***blent*** looks/sounds weird. I didn't know it until I just consulted OED, but *one* of the three etymologically distinct verbs ***to reeve*** (the nautical "threading rope" sense) has ***rove*** as a past tense form (before the 1700s, not *now*).

Comment: Etymologically unrelated to that nautical usage, ***reeve*** is also *To sift (winnowed grain, etc.)* and *To draw together or contract into wrinkles, folds, etc.; to pucker, wrinkle; to roll up (a sleeve).*

Answer (score 1):

Some of these words, even in their regular forms, would be archaic or poetic (i.e. difficult to understand) for a typical American speaker.

- "Shodden" is occurs primarily in the context of horses, but even then I've only ever seen "shod" as the past participle of "to shoe".
- I've never seen "chidden" and would be confused if I heard it, as it does not flow immediately from the already unusual word "chide", but it is apparently more of a word than "shodden" to my spellcheck.
- "Slidden" is very bizarre; my autocorrect does not recognize it as a word, nor can I claim to have ever seen it in any context.
- "Hove" might be familiar to some in the form of "hove to", the past participle form of "heave to".
- "Rove" and its base"reeve" might be passingly familiar to those with an interest in history... as a noun (a kind of local magistrate, still apparently a political position in parts of Canada). They might also be confused with "reave", meaning to raid/steal/plunder, perhaps from science fiction or fantasy literature. This is neither of them, apparently meaning "to pass a rope through," in a nautical context. As a verb with this particular meaning, I've never seen it before.
- "Blent" looks and sounds incorrect. I've never seen it, and would certainly raise an eyebrow at it if I did. Also not recognized by my spellcheck.
- "Gilt" is the most immediately recognizable to me, although a little poetic sounding. This is the only one in the list that I would be likely to
- "Girt" is unusual but possibly reasonable; "gird your loins" is the phrase that would immediately come to mind, and "girt" follows somewhat logically, although most would prefer "girded".

The [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shodden%2Cchidden%2Cslidden%2Chove%2Crove%2Cblent%2Cgilt%2Cgirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for these words roughly follow my feelings; gilt and hove are the most common, followed by girt and rove (I disagree on this one). Chidden, blent, shodden, and slidden are effectively rare enough to be nonexistent.

Comment: The past tense **hove** is only used in the nautical context. "At last the Indefatigable hove in sight" (Patrick O'Brian). **Gilt** is usually used as an adjective to describe a gold-painted object rather than an actual past participle.

Comment: And what about *chid*?